# Can't add local user as managed account Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-account, standalone

I am trying to add a local user on my machine as a managed account on my Sharepoint server. I''ve built the SharePoint server on a HyperV machine as a sandpit site and it is a single-Server config.

I get the error message account should only be used in stand alone mode.

Can somebody please shed some light on this for me as I'm not sure what the stand-alone mode is. Have researched it but nothing is helping me.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "A Managed Account is effectively an Active Directory user account
>   whose credentials are managed by and contained within SharePoint."

Which means that a local account can't be a managed account. However, you can use a local account to run all services on a SharePoint server.

Reference: [Managed Accounts in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2010/04/11/managed-accounts-in-sharepoint-2010/) by Bill Baer

Comment: Hey Benny. I understand what you are saying but in order to set an account as the "Service account" don't I have to register that user as a new "Managed account"? And this is where my problem lies as when I try to add the account I get the error shown above. This server isn't on the network and is working offline hence why I'm using local accounts. 

From my understanding you can'y have an account be a "service account" unless it is in the "managed accounts" list? Can I manually add the Service account through shell and that will overwrite it having to be a Managed Account?